# how would i have python check to see if a list was sent to/from socket server?

Tags: python, list, sockets, pickle

I'm trying to have a pickle file "server side" store a list of player coordinates. Server then sends that pickle file to the client. Also, i need a way for the client to look in the pickled file, for those coordinates.

How would i have the client look in the pickle file that would have all sorts of different information. And have it pull the coordinates from the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [unpickle](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) it at the client end and check for what you need to verify.

```
c = pickle.load( open( "fromserver.p" ) )
```

I am assuming that you are written  or writing both the server and the client part. And in which case, you decided upfront what you store and retrieve. For e.g. if you stored a list named `l` in the pickle file at the server end, at the client end you can unpickle and it is available to you as `l`

Comment: How would i check for info? Is there some sort of "search" function?  Like, Search for coords_data:
           if search = 1:
                coords get updated.

Comment: If you have the same classes on sending and receiving sides, unpickled objects will be of the right class.

Comment: @Shane O - I did not properly get what you mean by Search. Updated the answer however.

Comment: Well,I need a way to store multiple list or dictionary's. And, have the client get all the stored information from the server in one pass.

Comment: Note that you MUST NOT unpickle anything received from untrusted sources. It will allow injection of arbitrary code.